# Java Webservice hitting proxy instead of destination on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, proxy

I have a java webservice running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.39. It receives a message from another server on the same network then tries to send an outgoing message back. This outgoing message is being sent to NAProxy instead of the server it's supposed to.

I've turned off proxy settings in IE and the Java control panel. I've tried adding a ProxyServer variable to the cxf-beans file:

```
<http-conf:conduit name=".*http-conduit">
       <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="20000" ReceiveTimeout="30000" ProxyServer=""/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

but neither of these things work.

IE can reach the destination service from the outgoing server. I can hit the hosted destination service from the server using SOAPUI, so it's just a problem with the apache service, not the box.

It seems it is defaulting to use the proxy instead of a direct connection. Is there a setting somewhere to turn off proxy use?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy can be set also using system properties http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort. I don't know how your application is being started, but maybe somewhere there are JVM parameters -Dhttp.proxyHost=... -Dhttp.proxyPort=...
Since it is Tomcat, maybe you should check startup file.